# Model location of LUIS container service

Tags: azure, docker, azure-language-understanding

I am following this [instruction video](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/videos/language-understanding-container/) from Microsoft Azure team. 

`docker run`

has to come with where the model & data is located. Following the guide in the video, I download the 'exported data' from LUIS, say under `azure-luis/input`
then, I run the following command

```
docker run -i -t my-docker-image-repo-id EULA=accept BILLING=https://southcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0 APIKEY=my-unique-api-key --mount type=bind,input=/Users/#####/Developers/azure-luis/input --mount type=bind,source=/Users/#####/Developers/azure-luis/output
```

but I kept getting the following message

```
A folder must be mounted at the location '/input' where models and other input data can be read.
```

where did I do wrong?

Comment: Docker-specific options like `--mount` need to come _before_ the `my-docker-image-repo-id`.

Comment: Can you give me an example of running this docker service? I saw other issues. And the video is too blurry to see what has been entered.

Comment: ```docker run --rm -it -p 5000:5000 --memory 4g --cpus 2 \
--mount type=bind,src=/Users/my-user-name/Developers/azure-luis/input,target=/input \
--mount type=bind,src=/Users/my-user-name/Developers/azure-luis/output,target=/output \
mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cognitive-services/luis \
Eula=accept \
Billing= https://my-region.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0\
ApiKey={my-api-key} . - I use this command, and keep getting: issing BILLING=<value> command line option.

Comment: the steps are well detailed in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-container-howto

Comment: Solved. the problem I had is that there is an extra space of my billing url